# gnuplot automatic stack bar graph

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my data set:

```
type size name
label_0 1 nameOfData_0
label_0 2 nameOfData_1
label_0 3 nameOfData_2
label_1 2 nameOfData_3
label_2 1 nameOfData_4
label_0 2 nameOfData_5
label_1 3 nameOfData_6
label_3 2 nameOfData_7
label_3 1 nameOfData_8
```

I would like the plot to looks like:

[image]

I would like each label to be a stack and each nameOfData_X to fit in the correct stack according to its size. If possible add also the legend for each element of the stack.

I know I could reformat the data to process it easily via gnuplot but I don't want to.

Any ideas on how I could display this graph via gnuplot?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a way to achieve this with the gnuplot built-in stacked histogram style, check `help histograms`.
The following solution is not too obvious but seems to give the desired result and uses the plotting style `with boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`).

1. you need a list of unique elements of column 1. Here it will be in the order of the first occurrences.
2. during plotting in loops you add your contributions depending on a "filter" function `myAdd()`.
3. you change the color when the addition is zero (`dy=0`).
4. you add labels in a similar way with an offset

This code can probably be simplified but may act as a starting point.

**Code:**

```
### "manual" stacked histogram
reset session


$Data <<EOD
type size name
label_0 1 nameOfData_0
label_0 2 nameOfData_1
label_0 3 nameOfData_2
label_1 2 nameOfData_3
label_2 1 nameOfData_4
label_0 2 nameOfData_5
label_1 3 nameOfData_6
label_3 2 nameOfData_7
label_3 1 nameOfData_8
EOD

# get a unique list from datablock column 1
set table $Dummy
    Headers = 1
    addToList(list,col) = list.( strstrt(list,'"'.strcol(col).'"') > 0 ? '' : \
                          ' "'.strcol(col).'"')
    plot Uniques='' $Data u (Uniques=addToList(Uniques,1),'') skip Headers w table
unset table
N = words(Uniques)
Unique(i) = word(Uniques,i)

set xrange [1:N]
set xtics out noenhanced
set grid x,y
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0
unset key

set style fill transparent solid 0.7 border
myBoxWidth = 0.8
myAdd(colD,colF,i) = strcol(colF) eq Unique(i) ? column(colD) : 0
myLabel(col1,col2) = dy==0 ? '' : sprintf("%s\n%g",strcol(col1),column(col2))

plot for [i=1:N] y=y0=(c=1,0) $Data u (i):(dy=myAdd(2,1,i), y=y+dy,(y0+y)/2.): \
         (myBoxWidth/2.):(y0=y,dy/2.):(dy==0?c:c=c+1) skip Headers w boxxy lc variable, \
     for [i=1:N] y=y0=0 $Data u (i):(dy=myAdd(2,1,i), y=y+dy,(y0+y)/2.): \
         (y0=y,myLabel(3,2)):xtic(Unique(i)) skip Headers w labels offset 0,0.5 noenhanced
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad that I could help. Thanks on StackOverflow = accept and/or upvote.